# Redirect in $transition.onBefore in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using angular with components and ui-router 1.0.0-beta.3.
This version doesn't send events related to change state, there are hooks.
Before each state change I want to revalidate if user is authenticated and if has required roles. In case if not I want to redirect him to login page.

```
$transitions.onBefore({}, $transition => {

        const $toState = $transition.$to();

        if ($toState.data && $toState.data.authentication) {

            PrincipalService.identity().then(() => {
                return true;
            }, () => {
                console.log('redirecting');
                let $state = $transition.router.stateService;

                // not works
                //return $state.target('home');
                //return $transition.router.stateService.t('login');
            });
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve(false);
        }
    });
```

How to make this working ? With these cases I'm getting error about break the transition.

I based on [official documentation](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html)

Comment: Is that `1.0.0.alpha` the latest release ? OR  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/1.0.0-beta.3 ?

Comment: Yes, this this one -> "1.0.0-beta.3"

Comment: Tried transitionService?

Comment: Answered here: -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962954/angular-ui-router-transitions-onbefore

Answer (score 5):

Use `target` from `stateService` inside your condition.

`return $transition.router.stateService.target('login');`

You can see it at Migration Example 3 (https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events)

Comment: Here are the docs for that: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks#redirecting-a-transition

Answer (score 4):

Solution:

Use transitionTo(stateName); and return true to stop current transition.

```
$transition.router.stateService.transitionTo(stateName);
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

below worked for me

```
  $transition.abort();
  state.go('abcd')
```