# How to destroy angularjs directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transition

I have a AngularJS directive that I've inserted on the form of my SPA application. What it does is that it checks if the form is dirty before transitioning to a new state. Here is the code below.

```
app.directive('leavepage', ['$transitions', '$uibModal', '$q',
    function ($transitions, $modal, $q) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^form',
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attr, form) {
                $transitions.onBefore({}, function (transition) {

                    if (form.$dirty) {
                        return $q.when($modal.open({
                            backdrop: 'static',
                            keyboard: false,
                            controller: 'modalController',
                            template: "<div class='modal-header'><h5 class='modal-title'>Leave page?</h5></div>"
                                + "<div class='modal-body'><p>Changes you made may not be saved.</p></div>"
                                + "<div class='modal-footer'><button type='button' class='btn btn-light' ng-click='close(true)'>Cancel</button>"
                                + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-outline-success' ng-click='close(false)'>Leave</button></div>"
                        }).result.then(function (cancel) {
                            if (cancel) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

However, if the form is dirty and the user loads another form, the form.$dirty always remains true, and multiplies everytime another form gets dirty. Then the are you sure you want to leave template appears multiple times. How do I get this directive to remove itself when the transition is complete, and then reinsert itself in the new form?

Thank you and all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure returning false in promise will stop the transition as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962954/angular-ui-router-transitions-onbefore). The promise needs to be rejected.
2. Regarding the form, it's `dirty` state can be reset. Using [setPristine](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setPristine)

> $setPristine();
>
> Sets the form to its pristine state.
>
> This method sets the form's $pristine state to true, the $dirty state
> to false, removes the ng-dirty class and adds the ng-pristine class.
> Additionally, it sets the $submitted state to false.
>
> This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this
> form.
>
> Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want
> to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

Comment: A solution, but just a bandaid onto the real problem. It won't trigger the modal, but it doesn't delete the directive either.. Wouldn't this multiply and cause a bunch of issues the more the app is used?